# Graphics are shifted after using dvipdfmx

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, dvipdfmx

First of all, I hope it is okay to ask this question here. I really did not know where else.

So I'm generating a plot with gnuplot using the epslatex terminal.
For example,

```
set terminal epslatex standalone  
set output "foo.tex"

plot x title "x"
```

This generates foo.tex and foo-inc.eps.
I compile with `latex foo.tex` and get a foo.dvi which looks perfect.

[image: Good looking plot]

Now I convert this dvi to a pdf with `dvipdfmx foo.dvi` and the result is...

[image: Bad looking plot]

Any ideas how this can happen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why don't you do `pdflatex foo`?

Comment: @egreg Once, probably years ago, something I wanted to do wasn't working properly with pdflatex, and that's why I've done the latex - dvipdfmx ever since ;) I tried pdflatex, and (after including epstopdf) it is working fine - thanks! :) Still, would be nice to know what happens with dvipdfmx here. I guess it's a bug?